# Positioning and resizing a CSS split-colored triangle to desired position and proportions

Tags: css

Through help on stackoverflow I've been able to [generate and position a CSS triangle in the correct position on my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383955/make-a-css-generated-triangle-appearing-at-the-bottom-of-the-div-half-the-size), I've also learnt how to [color a triangle in 2 equal halves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299810/splitting-a-css-generated-triangle-into-2-horizontal-different-equal-colors).

But I am stuck on merging the two examples together, what I've tried I don't think is worth pasting here due to the mess I've made of it.

**I am trying to get a triangle that has the proportions and sits at the bottom of the div like [this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xcTAn/2/) and then is split in 2 colors like [this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/XandL/).**

Where I believe I am going wrong is that in the different fiddles there are different uses of:

```
:before
```

Answer (score 1):

*Well...,* Here is my attempt to achieve this effect (*proportions* + *split in 2 colors*):

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/xcTAn/6/)**.

In this demo, I added the `triangle` to the `.bottom` div and positioned that to stay at the top (with a negative value).

Then added `margin-top: 1%;` property to move the triangle when resizing the window:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.top {
    /* other styles... */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.bottom {
    background: lightGreen;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;       /* A lower z-index value than .top  */
                      /* Or use overflow: hidden; instead */
}

.triangle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1%;  /* Move the triangle when resizing the window */
    z-index: 1;
}

.triangle:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border-color: transparent blue transparent transparent;
}

.triangle:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 20px 0 0;
    border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: Good stuff, it looks pretty good on my end, will be looking a bit closer soon to see if I can find any issues. I am crossing my fingers!